Engineered Floors/Dreamweaver mislabeled sample. I used that sample to place my carpet order. The carpet that arrived on install day was lot thinner
I had ordered Engineered Floors Reflections I, got the sample back in October and it felt like a really nice carpet, easily beat out most of the Mohawk samples I got priced out. Proceeded to place the order and when the installers arrived, I checked the name and "model" on the carpet to ensure it was the correct one and left it that. Later on as they roll out the carpet, my dad calls me that this carpet feels a lot thinner than the sample, and sure enough, it is.
I called the dealer and he said send the installers back along with the sample as the dealer was going to have the salesman come out and compare between the sample and the ordered carpet. I felt terrible for the hassle caused and also really considered that this might just be from the compression/weight of the carpet being rolled up.
Today they confirmed the sample was mislabeled and that the sample carpet and the ordered carpet are 2 different things. They asked where I got the sample from, I pulled up the FedEx tracking number, and the address shows it is straight from the manufacturer in GA. The dealer said the salesman is going to conduct an investigation but it will be upto them if they want to cover the difference between the carpets. It sounded like they may have sent Reflections II/III instead of Reflections I.
Can I reasonably expect the manufacturer to cover the cost difference between the 2 carpets? Or should I prepare for a headache of potentially having to go carpet shopping again? TIA

They sent a sample claiming to be one thing and when you ordered you received something else?  Clearly they are responsible for their error and should make it good.  Hopefully you made it clear to them.

Exactly that, only thing is that I had ordered the sample in Acadia color and then ordered the product in Seashells. They were asking why I didn't order an Acadia sample, but truth be told, I was under a time crunch to make a decision and the Acadia was too grey for what we wanted so I just picked something more yellow aka Seashells.

This question will be closed because it really isn't about home improvement.
However I had almost the exact experience with carpet from one of the big box stores. Paid for one carpet.  Installers picked it up and installed it, but needed more. They went back to the store and it is discovered that the store had given the installers the wrong carpet originally.
The store gave me my money back for the carpet and padding AND gave me my choice of any carpet in the store, AND gave me a $200 store credit for the extra labor I paid.
I think the carpet store can satisfy you, especially through the manufacturer.

That seems more so store error in fulfilling your order rather than misdirection(mislabeling) into ordering the wrong thing in my case? But thank you, I sure do hope they can cover the difference in cost at least.
